# Refer to the base module in the test data - Odoo 11

Tags: inheritance, odoo, eval, odoo-11

I have a base module called `theater` with the following model called `ticket`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class ticket(models.Model):
    _name = 'theater.ticket'
    _rec_name = 'representation_id'

    price= fields.Float('Price',required=True)
    representation_id = fields.Many2one('theater.representation',string='Representation',required=True)
```

Then I create another extension module called `theater_extension`and add an additional field to `ticket`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class ticket(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'theater.ticket'

    individualTicket_id = fields.Many2one('theater_extension.individualTicket',string='Individual Ticket')
```

The problem comes when I add test data to `theater_extension`. I update the file `__manifest__.py`:

```
'demo': ['demo/dataTest.xml'],
```

And I create the `dataTest.xml`:

```
    <record id="ticket1" model="theater.ticket">
        <field name="representation_id" ref="theater.representation1"></field>
        <field name="price">22</field>
        <field name="seats_ids"
        eval="[(6, 0, [ref(theater.seat1),ref(theater.seat2)])]"></field>
    </record>
```

> Note: The model `seat` and seat1 and seat2 are created in the base (theater)
>   module.

The problem is that it does not find the theater module in the following line:

```
        eval="[(6, 0, [ref(theater.seat1),ref(theater.seat2)])]" model="theater.seat"></field>
```

Error reported:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "<class 'NameError'>: "name 'theater' is not defined" while evaluating
'[(6, 0, [ref(theater.seat1),ref(theater.seat2)])]'" while parsing /home/usuario/odoo-dev/theater_extension/demo/dataTest.xml:18, near
<record id="ticket1" model="theater.ticket">
        <field name="representation_id" ref="theater.representation1"></field>
        <field name="price">22</field>
        <field name="seats_ids"
        eval="[(6, 0, [ref(theater.seat1),ref(theater.seat2)])]"></field>
</record>
```

Comment: Did you add ticket module's python file name to `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the error is very simple but hard to spot, `ref` accepts a string representation of `XML-ID` and you forgot to put quotes around your IDs:

```
      eval="[(6, 0, [ref('theater.seat1'), .....])]"
```

Because you didn't put those quotes when the expression is evaluated python will treat them as variables and this is why you are having this error because there is no reference called theater.